# Generit type of class prevents checking of generic type of argument (compile and runtime)

Tags: java, generics, casting

I am passing an `List` with generic type to a method `method`. Normally Java checks these generic types. But if the method is on a  class which itself has a generic type, it does not detect the problem:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SODemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<ClsAlpha> list = new ArrayList<>();
    (new OtherCls()).method(list);
    System.out.println(list.get(0));
  }
}

// Without this <T> the problem IS detected
class OtherCls<T> {
  public void method(List<ClsBeta> list) {
    list.add(new ClsBeta());
  }
}

class ClsAlpha {}
class ClsBeta {}
```

For me, this code compiles and runs. If the `<T>` is removed, it doesn't compile.

I am surprised about both: I would expect Java to detect the mismatch in arguments. And I would expect that, if it does compile, it will raise a `ClassCastException` (I know type information is erased, but I thought there would be casts in the compiled code).

Can anyone enlighten me?

**SOLUTION**: if an object accepts a generic type `T` but an instance isn't given one, then all generic types (not only `T`, also others) for it's arguments are erased. So in the code, `OtherCls` is raw type, therefore `public void method(List<ClsBeta> list)` is really `public void method(List list)`. Details in the question that this turned out to be a duplicate of.

Comment: The answer is the duplicate's top rated answer.

Comment: Thanks, I was using the wrong words it seems